# Export polyline from google maps as JSON or GeoJSON

Tags: json, google-maps, export, geojson, polyline

Is there a way to *save/export* a poly-line from google maps in some file format (eg. JSON), without using any JS.

[image: Google map with polyline]

I am thinking, if a client would set up a private google map with poly-lines if she could export the paths from there in some format? The path files would then get imported into a CMS and displayed on a custom map on the front-end.

Comment: The Interaction with the map is in general performed with JS. Without JS you can´t as far as i know to access the data. But why don´t you just take the data with JS, send it to the server and do your stuff??

Comment: That could be an option to consider, thanks.

Comment: Guess this is your only option, but we will see ;) A simple way of storing and restoring is using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility .

Comment: I see now though you can export the map data as a KML file - which can be converted to a JSON quite easily.

Comment: without any js?

Comment: @elsololobo - export to KML file screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/8ddb8c271d5484285ea62f3bd89ef39f.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to export as KML, which can be converted to JSON.

[image]